# copying reports from a reporting database to antoher

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am a total newbie in SQL/SQL server stuff, and I am using SSRS to make a new reporting server/service and upload some .rdl files to it

I have a reporting server on a machine, which has a lot of reports and data sources uploaded to it's database.

I created a new reporting server with a fresh database on another machine, and what I want to do is to copy the old database content to the fresh one (the reports and the datasources..etc)

I have no copy of the individual reports to upload them to the new server using localhost/reports

is there's a fast solution to what i am having? please do it in detail because I never worked with SQL before.

Comment: Hmm, standard backup/restore, no?

Comment: Have you looked at this article, which has specific step by step instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to do this:

### Report Server Databases

Use the detach/attach or backup/restore instructions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421.aspx). Both of these methods require a backup of encryption keys on the existing instance, which are then restored to the new report server instance. Instructions on backup/restore of encryption keys [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157275.aspx). Migrating the `ReportServer` and `ReportServerTempdb` databases is the easiest way to ensure **all** content is available on the new server.

### Report Object Scripting

[Reporting Services Scripter](http://sqlserverfinebuild.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Reporting%20Services%20Scripter) is an older (but still working with SSRS 2008R2, not sure about 2012) tool that can be used to transfer objects (folders, shared data sources, shared data sets, reports, etc) between report servers. Good choice if you want to pick and choose what is migrated.

---

If you are receiving  an error regarding unsupported scale-out deployment, this means you are running Standard edition and need to remove the old report server entry from the database in the new location. It can be done using Reporting Services Configuration Manager, or by using `rskeymgmt` at command line.

### Reporting Services Configuration Manager

1. Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager and connect to the new report server instance.
2. Click on `Scale-out Deployment` to view registered report servers.
3. Select the old report server instance and click the *Remove Server* button.

[image: Reporting Services Configuration Manager]

### Command line and `rskeymgmt`

1. Browse to the `Tools\Binn` folder of your SQL Server client installation.
2. Run the following to list registered report servers

   rskeymgmt -l -i
3. Using the installation ID (GUID) of the old report server, remove it

   rskeymgmt -r  -i

More info on scale-out deployments and `rskeymgmt` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155931.aspx).

Comment: I did that and it went smoothly, but now when i navigate localhost/reports it shows "the feature: scale-out deployment is not supported in this edition of reporting services. (rsoperation notsupported) (rsRPCError)" i am sure that this db was working on the other machine.

Comment: @SherifMaherEaid Edited with information on resolving the scale-out deployment error.

Answer (score 1):

To migrate Reporting Services, use migration manual from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143724(v=sql.120).aspx). If you encounter "the feature: scale-out deployment is not supported in this edition of reporting services. (rsoperation notsupported)" error, go to ReportServer database and remove the old encryption key from table dbo.Keys.